# How to create multiple COM Instances via C#

Tags: c#, com, instance

i try to Start two instances of Application like this:

```
var t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Application",null);
var app1 = Activator.GetInstance(t);
var app2 = Activator.GetInstance(t);
```

It launches the first application and the second is a copy of the first, not the new instance.

How to run two different app?

Comment: The code snippet is nonsense, surely you actually use Activator.CreateInstance().  Whether a second call will actually launch another instance of the out-of-process COM server is not under your control, the server decides this.  It is the one that uses the [REGCLS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679697%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) value.  If it is a "heavy" app or has singleton behavior then usually not.  Call the vendor or author, you have a No, maybe you'll get a Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
var t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Application",null);

var app1 = Activator.GetInstance(t);

var t1 = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Application",null);

var app2 = Activator.GetInstance(t1);
```

Comment: let me try, whhich app i will answer soon

Comment: It does not matter which app. [A `Type` object that represents a type is unique; that is, two `Type` object references refer to the same object if and only if they represent the same type. This allows for comparison of `Type` objects using reference equality](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). That is, your `t` and `t1` contain references to exactly same object, and your code is identical to the OP's.

Comment: @GSerg but it not true if the app is Internet explorer app is that possible that they both you referrence to the same COM OBJECT but they be 2 other diffrent object

Comment: The `type` object returned by `GetTypeFromProgID` will be the same. The contents of `t` and `t1` is identical in your code. It is *not* about creating instances of this type.

Comment: oh ok i get what you mean